# Xamarin.Android 7+: Crash/SIGSEGV with interop callback with struct parameter from native to managed

Tags: callback, crash, xamarin.android, interop, segmentation-fault

edit: added logcat output and link to sample project.

Hello,

I get a crash with SIGSEGV in a very specific callback case of a native library doing a callback to a managed delegate and I could reproduce it in the attached sample.

There are other simpler cases in which it works even with a structure, but with one specific case it just crashes.

Please read carefully the explanations below.

The sample is very simple:
There is a native library (libcallback.so), for which source code can be found in callback.c.

This library implements three callbacks with different parameters as described below:

"callback": this is the one that crashes, it uses a complex structure with const sized array fields.
"other_callback": this is another example of callback with a structure pointer parameter. This one is a little simpler and it works just fine.
"func": this is a callback with a very simple parameter.

Then the C# code creates 3 button (CALLBACK, OTHER CB and FUNC CB).
Each button click will raise an indirect (asynchrone) call to the callback corresponding to its name.

So when a button is pressed a call to the native library is made.
The native library creates a new thread and the thread makes a callback to the managed code.
When callbacked the managed code then outputs a log message corresponding to the callback that was made.

When using this sample, the "other_callback" and "func" callbacks work fine.
However "callback" will crash (tested in Xamarin.Android 7.2 and 7.4).

Important: this same project WORKS FINE when compiled with Xamarin 6.0, or on Windows (c Code must be adapted to export the functions and not use pthread on windows but if we do this it works).

I know that the callback argument doesn't fully correspond to the C structure, but even though I consider that it should work because:
1) The C structure is larger so even if mono makes an internal copy it should be able to truncate the data it needs without access violation.
2) This project works fine if build using Xamarin.Android 6.0.
3) This project works fine on Windows.

I also noted that if I comment out the last 4 fields of the EST_E_DATA structure in C#, then Callback will be called without crash (see example below).

So questions:
- Why does it crash when built with Xamarin 7.2 and 7.4?
- Why doesn't it crash if I remove the array declarations?
- Why doesn't it crash on Windows or when built with Xamarin 6.0?

Below is the example of removing the arrays declaration for EST_E_DATA structure:

```
    public struct EST_E_DATA
    {
        public Int16 s;
        public Int16 v;
        public UInt32 p;
        public UInt32 e;
        public Int32 l;
        public Int32 ll;
        public UInt16 h;
        public Int16 r;
        public Int16 pp;
        public Int32 hh;
        public Int32 bn;
        public Int32 dn;
        public Int32 dr;
        public Int32 sh;
        public Int32 ra;
    }
```

Edit:
Crash message is as follow, without any relevant information to debug:
01-01 14:33:35.343: E/mono-rt(4886): No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output).
01-01 14:33:35.343: E/mono-rt(4886): =================================================================
01-01 14:33:35.343: E/mono-rt(4886): Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
01-01 14:33:35.343: E/mono-rt(4886): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
01-01 14:33:35.343: E/mono-rt(4886): used by your application.
01-01 14:33:35.343: E/mono-rt(4886): =================================================================
01-01 14:33:35.343: A/libc(4886): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 4914 (ec.callbacktest)

01-01 14:33:35.443: I/DEBUG(2161): Revision: '405522'
01-01 14:33:35.443: I/DEBUG(2161): pid: 4886, tid: 4914, name: ec.callbacktest  >>> fec.callbacktest <<<
01-01 14:33:35.443: I/DEBUG(2161): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
01-01 14:33:35.583: I/DEBUG(2161):     r0 00000000  r1 00001d50  r2 0000000f  r3 00000012
01-01 14:33:35.583: I/DEBUG(2161):     r4 76affd08  r5 59b20188  r6 63c884a4  r7 63cbe454
01-01 14:33:35.583: I/DEBUG(2161):     r8 63cbaf05  r9 00100000  sl 00000000  fp 76affdd8
01-01 14:33:35.583: I/DEBUG(2161):     ip 68925364  sp 76affd08  lr 40cbf084  pc 40cbf088  cpsr 80000010

Sample can be dowloaded from here:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/attachment.cgi?id=24525

PS: I registered a bug about this also in Xamarin bugzilla database, but I don't have big hopes as to their answer so I also would like asking on SO if someone understand the issue and can propose a workaround.
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59182

Actually it is possible to avoid the crash by changing the Callback declaration to use unsafe pointer to structure, but I don't understand why this works and why the other declaration would crash.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't post an exception message, but it is possible the reason of dynamically linking against non-NDK libraries. Checked this doc: [Preparing for Native Library Linking Changes in Android N](https://blog.xamarin.com/preparing-for-native-library-linking-changes-in-android-n/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Exception message was added, with the link to the sample project to download. However there is no information in the log it's just a SIGSEGV/SEGV_MAPERR. Then we are deploying on Jellybean so we are not affected by this issue, but good to know.